# WebSocket Server for MKR1000

Tags: programming, library, websocket

I was looking for a websocket server for my MKR1000 but nothing I found works.

I tried all the libraries that come with Arduino but half of those don't compile on the MKR1000 and those that do it don't work at all.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is a dedicated  WiFi/Ethernet Shield that supports websocket server. But it is only worked with Uno and Mega. This shield name is PHPoC Shield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This relatively simple one has always worked for me on several Arduinos (but I haven't tried it on the MKR1000 specifically):

https://github.com/morrissinger/ESP8266-Websocket

I have forked it and made some changes, but nothing fundamental:

https://github.com/ocrdu/NINA-Websocket

Have a go; it will probably work for you. Note that it works on more Arduinos than the name suggests; it's quite universal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but devices based on ESP8266, doesn't work

Comment: IIRC (it's been a while), this websocketserver works on other Arduinos as well, it's more universal than the name suggests.

Comment: Thanks Ocrdu, https://github.com/ocrdu/NINA-Websocket works fine . I didn't use WiFinina I use instead WiFi101 and work ok.